# BH1750FVI with I2C won't work

Tags: atmega, c, i2c

I have the led driver of Adafruit connected to my atmega32. I adjusted their library for the Arduino, so now I just need a µcontroller and not an Arduino. This thing works.

Now I want to control the brightness of the leds with a BH1750FVI.
I use the I2C library of Peter Fleury, [library download link](http://homepage.hispeed.ch/peterfleury/i2cmaster.zip). Then I added some code so I can get values out of the sensor and adjust the brigtness of my leds and here things go wrong.

I initialize the I2C, then I send to the sensor to wake up, give me a measurement at High resolution of 1Lx and go back to sleep. Normally this should work but nothing happens to my leds, even my blinking leds (not dependent on the measurement of the sensor) doesn't work.

Because the sensor works on 3.3V and my atmega32 works on 5V, I use a [jy-mcu logic level controller](http://www.thaieasyelec.com/products/interface-modules/logic-level/jy-mcu-iic-level-converter-module-detail.html).

What am I doing wrong or is it maybe my jy-mcu logic level controller?

my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <compat/twi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "i2cmaster.h"

#define adres 0x23

/** Calculate from the sensor values to the pwm levels for the leds */
int calcLight(unsigned char lightData){
    int lData = (int) lightData;
    if(lData == 0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        int calcData = round(lData / 655.35);
        calcData = round(calcData * 40.95);

        return calcData;
    }
}

unsigned char getData(){
    unsigned char data = 0x0000;

    if(i2c_start(adres + I2C_WRITE)){           // set device address and write mode
        i2c_stop();                             /* failed to issue start condition, possibly no device found */

        return 0x0000;                          // deactivate all 8 LEDs to show error */
    }else{
        i2c_write(0x01);
        i2c_stop();

        i2c_start_wait(adres + I2C_WRITE);  // set device address and write mode
        i2c_write(0x10);

        if(i2c_rep_start(adres + I2C_READ)){        // set device address and read mode
            i2c_stop();

            return 0x0000;
        }else{
            data = i2c_readAck() << 8;              // read MSB
            data = data + i2c_readNak();            // read and shift LSB
            i2c_stop();

            return data;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int lightData = 100;
    unsigned char data = 0x0000;

    tlc5947(2);
    begin();
    i2c_init();

    ledsOff();
    write();
    _delay_ms(5000);

    while(1){
        data = getData();
        if(data != 0x0000){
            lightData = calcLight(data);
        }

        if(lightData <= 100){
            setPWM(4, 100);
        }else{
            setPWM(4, lightData);
        }

        setPWM(19, 2000); // control blinking led
        setPWM(28, 2000); // control blinking led
        write();
        _delay_ms(5000);
        ledsOff();
        write();
        _delay_ms(5000);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

PS.: I'm new to I2C.

Comment: Can you provide link for your lib or getData() and write() functions? One more thing, What are your expected values for `data` which you will pass to `calcLight()`. Put a breakpoint after `getData()` and see whether you are getting any data... This is to make sure that issue is with I2C or your code!

Comment: I adjusted my code and added the link to Peter Fleury's i2c library.
In the datasheet is writen that the light sensor has a range from 0 to 65535. I convert this in calcLight from 0 to 4095 PWM range of the led driver.

Now for the breakpoint: How can I do this if I program the code into the µcontroller using Extreme Burner?

Comment: Could it be that I need pull-up resistors? Now it's connected like this: µc<---->logic level controller<----->BH1750FVI without pull-ups. If this is my problem where should I place these resistors (between µc and llc or llc and sensor or both?

Comment: Yes... You need pullups on I2C lines

Comment: I don't know if there are already pull-ups on my bh1750fvi board. Which value is used for a pull-up resistor?

Comment: Here is my board: http://www.ebay.com/itm/BH1750FVI-Digital-Light-intensity-Sensor-Module-For-AVR-Arduino-3V-5V-power-/261201621666

Comment: I added 10k pull-ups at each data and clk line at both sides of the llc. Still it doesn't work.